# Pentaho send unwanted email when no errors in Kettle

Tags: pentaho

I have this job alert on Pentaho, when the job fails it sends me an email.

[image]

However, even if the whole ETL flow is running correctly. I am receiving an email.

that's my setting for the false result

[image]

The email I receive after I run my whole ETL flow.

[image]

I only want to receive an email when the jobs failed, how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure all the connections to the *Send mail* action in the job are set to "Follow when Result is False"? I can see a green connection within all the bunch of red connections.